# Find $\int \frac{e^{-x}\sin x}{x} \ dx$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, analysis, indefinite-integrals

I'm trying to compute $\int \frac{e^{-x}\sin x}{x} \ dx$.  This resembles integrating $\int e^{-x}\sin x \ dx$ so my main thought about how to approach this is by finding some connection with that.  I know that $\int e^{-x}\sin x \ dx = -\frac 1 2 e^{-x}(\sin x + \cos x)$. If I try to use integration by parts setting

$$u=x^{-1}$$

and

$$dv=e^{-x}\sin x \ dx$$

then we get

$$\frac{du}{dx}=-\frac{1}{x^2}$$

and also

$$v=-\frac 1 2 e^{-x}(\sin x + \cos x)$$

Then the integral becomes

$$ \int u \ dv = uv-\int v\ du = x^{-1}\left(-\frac 1 2 e^{-x}(\sin x + \cos x) \right) - \int \left( -\frac 1 2 e^{-x}(\sin x + \cos x) \right) \left( -\frac{1}{x^2} \right) \ dx $$

I seem to have made things worse.  I am sorry.

If I try to make any other assignment of $u$ and $dv$ in integration by parts, I don't foresee them going any better.  No substitution seems helpful, either $u$ or trig.  I don't think I can integrate twice and get back to where I started.  That almost seems possible if I take what I have done above and now choose $\frac 1 {x^2}$ for integration, except that the derivative part will now have much more in it than I started with.  I think my bag of tricks may be empty.

Comment: The antiderivative can be expressed in terms of a special function, the [exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral). And no need to apologize :)

Comment: Have you tried putting it into Wolfram Alpha?

Comment: Clearly, the integral is $\int_{0}^{x}\frac{e^{-t}\sin t}{t} \, dt$ + C ;)

Comment: @user170231's legacy: $$-\frac{\mathrm{i}\left(\operatorname{Ei}\left(\left(\mathrm{i}-1\right)x\right)-\operatorname{Ei}\left(-\left(\mathrm{i}+1\right)x\right)\right)}{2}+C$$

Comment: Yes but how @vitamind, anyone can put this integral into Wolfam and get an answer, but how

Comment: @SomeGuy That's why it's a comment. To answer your question: Use Eulers formula.

Comment: I feel very bad for you if you spent a long time trying to integrate this. Keep in mind that most functions don't have antiderivatives that can expressed in terms of elementary functions. For instance, we can't integrate $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ either. (Or, rather, we *can*, but we can't express the result in terms of polynomials, trig functions, exponentials or the logarithm etc.)

Comment: What does "most functions don't have an antiderivative" mean? Infinitely many functions have one and infinitely many functions don't have one.

Comment: @vitamind In this context, I was using the word 'most' informally to mean that if I randomly think up a function, chances are I can't integrate it. It is also possible to argue that the cardinality of functions that have elementary antiderivatives is smaller than the cardinality of functions that have antiderivatives which are not elementary, I believe. (But I have no knowledge whatsoever about this.)

Comment: @Joe Yes I understand. It was a rhetorical question. I think "often" should do it. Have a nice day!

Comment: @vitamind: Thank you, and you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no one is going to post an answer I will prove that
$$I = \int \frac{e^{-x}\sin x}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x = -\frac{\mathrm{i}\left(\operatorname{Ei}\left(\left(\mathrm{i}-1\right)x\right)-\operatorname{Ei}\left(-\left(\mathrm{i}+1\right)x\right)\right)}{2}+C,$$
where $\operatorname{Ei}$ is the expontial integral and $C$ is an arbitrary real constant.

*Lemma.* Let $z$ be a complex number. Then
$$\sin z = \frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}.$$
If we rewrite the sine in the integral, we may add exponents and use linearity of the integral to get to
$$I = \frac{1}{2i}\int \frac{e^{ix-x}}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x-\frac{1}{2i}\int \frac{e^{-ix-x}}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x.$$
Substitute in the first integral $u_1=(i-1)x$ and in the second one $u_2=-(i+1)x$.
$$\frac{1}{2i}\operatorname{Ei}(u_1)-\frac{1}{2i}\operatorname{Ei}(u_2).$$
Substituting $u_{1,2}$ back yields
$$\frac{\operatorname{Ei}((i-1)x)-\operatorname{Ei}(-(i-1)x)}{2i}+C.$$
The last step is a matter of taste. You can write $\tfrac{1}{i}$ as $-i$, so
$$\frac{-i(\operatorname{Ei}((i-1)x)-\operatorname{Ei}(-(i-1)x))}{2}+C.$$