# Proof from the definition that the outer measure of any open set is the sum over its interval lengths.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

Let $|A|$ denote the outer-measure of a set of real numbers $A\subseteq \Bbb R$.  Let $\{I_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ be a sequence of disjoint open intervals.  I want to prove that $\left|\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty I_n\right| = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \ell(I_n)$.

---

I know that $|I|=\ell(I)$ for any individual interval, and I have monotonicity, and sub-additivity.  This seems like it should be enough but I haven't been able to show it.

Of course $\{I_n\}$ is already a countable open interval cover of $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty I_n$ and therefore $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ell(I_n)$ is in the set of all sums of lengths.  It then suffices to show that it's a lower-bound on the set of sums of lengths.

But if you take any open interval cover $\{J_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$, so that $\cup_{n=1}^\infty I_n \subseteq \cup_{n=1}^\infty J_n$, then we need to show

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \ell(I_n) \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \ell(J_n)$$

Monotonicity only gives

$$\left|\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty I_n\right|\le \left|\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty J_n\right|$$

and sub-additivity gives

$$ \left|\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty I_n\right|\le \sum_{n=1}^\infty |I_n| = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \ell(I_n)$$

and likewise for the $J$'s.

---

So it doesn't seem like I can handle this with theorems.  I know $\cup J_n$ is an open set and therefore a countable union of open intervals.  Maybe I can sort of replace $\{J_n\}$ with a sequence $\{K_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ where the $K_n$'s are formed from taking unions of any overlapping $J_n$'s.  I think that's not hard, maybe by defining an equivalence relation on $\{J_n\}$.  But then how could you prove that $\sum \ell(K_n)\le \sum \ell (J_n)$?  It's intuitively correct, but making a rigorous argument which is valid for infinitely many terms is not clear to me.

Comment: $\cup_{n=1}^\infty J_n$ is itself a countable union of $disjoint$ intervals.

Comment: Hi @Addem. If my answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4041351/find-int-frace-x-sin-xx-dx/4041405#4041405) question has helped you, I'd appreciate a checkmark :) (btw, will delete this comment after you've seen it since it's off-topic here.)

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution.  It's not perfect because it relies on something that seems a little too powerful to be "from scratch".  But it's better than nothing:

Suppose that we already know $m^*(A\cup G)=m^*(A)+m^*(G)$ if $G$ is an open set and $A\cap G=\emptyset$.  Therefore for empty sets we get finite additivity.  Note that then if $\{I_n\}_{1\le n\le m}$ is a finite collection of disjoint open intervals then by monotonicity

$$\sum_{n=1}^m\ell(I_n) = m^*\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^m I_n\right) \le m^*\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty I_n\right)$$

Since this is true for each $m\in\Bbb N$ we can take the limit as $m\to\infty$.